# Django DeleteView __str__ returned non-string (type model name)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement DeleteView. However, I get the following TypeError :

```
__str__ returned non-string (type Fund)
```

How can I solve this?

many thanks to all in advance,

Code :

Fund model :

```
class Fund(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = 'default')
 amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)

 def __str__ (self):
    return self.name
```

views.py :

```
class CashFlowDelete(DeleteView):
 model = CashFlow
 success_url = reverse_lazy('fds:fds')
```

urls.py:

```
path('deletecashflow/<int:pk>/', views.CashFlowDelete.as_view(),name = "delete_cashflow"),
```

funds_detail.html

```
<a href="{% url 'fds:delete_cashflow' pk=cashflow.pk %}">Delete</a>
```

cashflow_confirm_delete.html

```
<form method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
 <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

Comment: There is likely something wrong with your `Fund` model. Can you share this? Did you override the `__str__`? It is also possible that the error is in the `Cashflow` model.

Comment: I've included it

Answer (score 0):

> `__str__` must return string and your `__str__` is return other than
>   string.

For Example
here price is converted to string using **f'strings**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.price}'
```

> You can format string in may ways some of them are. Check Python version while converting to string
>
> - `str(self.price)`
> - `"{}".format(self.price)`
> - `"%s" % (self.price)`
> - `f"{self.price}"` *f-string in python 3.6+ only*

Answer (score 0):

All,
Managed to solve the point. In fact there was an issue in my template.

This is the corrected template:

```
<form method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ form }}"?</p>
 <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

all the best, and thanks to everyone for helping me out